# 3 Issues Regarding .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have the following .htaccess snippet, I don't understand it at all, and I am trying to simply fix few problems:

1 - How to make www.domain.co.uk and domain.co.uk and both with /index.php at the end to re-direct to the home page? as I have heard it is not good for SEO.

2 - I want to remove the .php that is after any URL (This already been done, but I don't know which line is for it in the above snippet).

3 - I have a database that I add projects to, and it generate the URL for projects that I add one of the URLs is "http://www.domain.co.uk/projects.php?project=Websites" how to get rid of ".php?project=" and make it look like www.domain.co.uk/projects/Websites

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.co.uk/404.php
ErrorDocument 504 /504.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co\.uk$

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**NEW - We are working on it from the comments and answers below:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 504 /504

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

# remove index
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately
# The trailing slash is removed in a next request, so be efficient and
# dont put it on there at all
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1 [R=301,L]

# remove slash if not directory
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
# On some hosts RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f will be true, even if
# no such file exists. Be safe and add an extra condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\.php)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

#Hey, this one is fine ;-)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: No mate that is all :/ it is abit confusing all these lines and I have no clue where to start

Comment: Where does the double `RewriteEngine on` and the orphan `RewriteCond`'s above the second `RewriteEngine on` come from? Begin with removing those.

Comment: oh, just did and look above - there is a new section for the new code that will be working on

Comment: I did some tests on the actual site, and the url's it redirects me too are certainly interesting. I'll write up an answer for you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is certainly interesting. The rules you have would work fine on their own, but create a mess when used together. The problem is that you are using the `R` flag without the `L` flag. You are working with a mix of full url's and normal url's.

A request to `example.com/otherpage.php` ends up being rewritten to:

```
1. 301: http://www.example.com/http://example.com/home/yourhome/public_html/otherpage
2. 302: http://www.example.com/404.php
3. 301: http://www.example.com/404
4. 200: (and finally this page gives a 200 - OK status code)
```

A request to `example.com/index.php` follows an even weirder pattern:

```
1. 301: http://www.example.com/http://example.com/home/yourhome/public_html/
2. 301: http://www.example.com/http:/example.com/home/yourhome/public_html
3. 302: http://www.example.com/404.php
4. 301: http://www.example.com/404
5. 200: (and finally this page gives a 200 - OK status code)
```

---

So how to fix this? See the following `.htaccess` (put comments inside for easier understanding)

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
#/404.php redirects to /404, so why not do this immediately?
ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 504 /504

#These do nothing useful, so remove them
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loaidesign\.co\.uk$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loaidesign\.co\.uk$

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

# remove index
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately
# The trailing slash is removed in a next request, so be efficient and
# dont put it on there at all
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1 [R=301,L]

# remove slash if not directory
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
# On some hosts RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f will be true, even if
# no such file exists. Be safe and add an extra condition
# There is no point in escaping a dot in a string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\.php)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

#The regex part of the rewritecondition must escape the dots.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loaidesign\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Make sure your `/404.php` sends out an actual 404 Not Found header. The `200 OK` header states to, for example a search engine, that the page exists. The same is true for your `/504.php` page. Besides that your 504.php gives several warnings.

Comment: Please view the edit on the NEW section in my question, is that how it suppose to be? I now understand most of these lines you are answer really explained lot - however what about the Project URL?

Comment: @Leo daker gave a good answer on that part of the question, and I didn't feel the need to copy him.

Comment: I understand mate however I have tried it and add RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ projects.php?project=$1 [L] at the end of the code but it did nothing :/ live preview can be found here: http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/projects.php?project=Wix_Websites

Comment: I've made one more edit to my answer since you copied it. Forgot about the escaping issues. That and the status codes.

Comment: Changed t, everything seem to be working fine aprat from the projects page :/ Please help

Comment: If you test it, and it 'does nothing', debug what happens. In this case I think rule 4 matches before your new rule (displaying `/projects/Wix_websites.php`. Moreover, any relative url's think this is actually directory `/projects`. Adding it -before- the redirects doesn't seem like a wise plan, but maybe if you place it under the redirects, and above the other internal rewrites it will magically start to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42977/discussion-between-leo-and-sumurai8)

Comment: Does this line really do the trick? RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ projects.php?project=$1 [L] I tried it as you said and no hope, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1. This is not bad for SEO. And if you don't want /index.php to your url just don't link it that way. Remove /index.php from your links.
2. These lines adds ".php" to a file request. So if you link http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/somefile the server will request 
   http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/somefile.php. It may also redirect somefile.css to somefile.css.php, but only if somefile.css.php exists.

   ```
   # add .php to access file
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
   ```
3. Rewrite your URL generation code to output links on the format you want (www.loaidesign.co.uk/projects/Wix_Websites) and add this to your .htaccess

   ```
   RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ projects.php?project=$1 [L]
   ```

   Then you can access your _GET as usual ($_GET['project'] will be equal to Wix_Websites in the obove example)

Comment: Please take a look at the updated version, is that how it suppose to be?

Answer (score 0):

Change (new code)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loaidesign\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.loaidesign\.co\.uk$
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```

(i.e., partially restore the original). Those two RewriteConds are doing nothing.

For (1), your old last two lines are correct to add www. to any domain name missing it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loaidesign\.co\.uk  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.loaidesign.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For (2), you want a more SEO/SEF URL, without the .php? You remove the .php *elsewhere*, such as your links or what the user types in, and *add* .php back in here in .htaccess, so that the server then works with filename.php. Remove

```
# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

and replace it with

```
# add .php to any suspected file lacking one
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php  -f
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  $1.php  [L]
```

Note that this *is* **rewriting** the URI... it will not show up in the address bar, since there is no 30x return code.

Number (3) is standard SEO coding. First, *your* links must produce it in that format `/projects/Wix_Websites` -- .htaccess does not do that. In .htaccess, you convert it back into a form that the server understands: `/projects.php?project=Wix_Websites`. The question is: how general do you want to make this? Do you want *any* `/XX/AA` to become `XX.php?YY=AA`, or just specific ones like projects?

The "remove slash if not directory" I *think* will work, as is, if you want to put that back in.